# Getting "tailwindcss: Unknown word" error in my React project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[image: the error what it showing it]

I have downloaded and followed all the steps still not able to fix the error and not able to understand the issue
Description:
I'm working on a React project and trying to set up Tailwind CSS for styling. However, I'm encountering an error message that says "tailwindcss: Unknown word." I have followed the installation steps and configured my project, but I can't seem to resolve this issue.

Error Message:
"tailwindcss: Unknown word"

Steps I've Taken:

```
Created a new React project using Create React App.
Installed Tailwind CSS using npm install tailwindcss.
Configured the tailwind.config.js file.
Created a src/tailwind.css file and imported base, components, and utilities.
```

Comment: Please share your `tailwind.config.js` file

Comment: Also, can you restart your VS Code and see whether issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may have the [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) VSCode extension installed. This flags *spelling* errors and does not necessarily indicate anything wrong with the underlying code from a machine's perspective.

Regardless, to make the error in VSCode go away you could:

- [Add comments to ignore words in the file](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker#in-document-settings) like:

  ```css
  /* cSpell:ignore tailwindcss */
  @import "tailwindcss/base";
  @import "tailwindcss/components";
  @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
  ```

  Or

  ```css
  /* cspell:disable */
  @import "tailwindcss/base";
  @import "tailwindcss/components";
  @import "tailwindcss/utilities";
  ```

  Etc.
- [Customize cspell settings via `cspell.json`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker#cspell.json) to add `tailwindcss` as a correctly spelled word:

  ```json
  {
    // Version of the setting file.  Always 0.2
    "version": "0.2",
    // words - list of words to be always considered correct
    "words": [
        "tailwindcss"
    ]
  }
  ```
- [Customize the extension settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker#vs-code-configuration-settings) to ignore the word:

  ```json
  {
    "cSpell.words": [
      "tailwindcss"
    ]
  }
  ```